# php - inserting html tags based on condition

Tags: php, html

Using php I wish to wrap div tags around some content based on whether a condition is met. Currently I am doing this as displayed in the example below. Is there a better way of doing this? It does not seem to be very professional.

```
<?php if($Subject) echo "<div id='someID'>";?>

    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem
 Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
 printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has 
survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining
 essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
 containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
 Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

<?php if($Subject) echo "</div>";?>
```

Comment: I don't think that's very unprofessional. But you have to tell us maybe more about your case to get sure.

Comment: Use a template engine.

Comment: It only applies to two pages so i'm reluctant to adopt a template engine approach for just two pages. As regards more about my case - basically i split the page into tabbed content if a condition is met as it means another section is needed. Currently it works fine, i just don't like the idea of having php code echoing closing tags scattered over my page.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this, by hiding the div

```
  <div id="someID" <?php if (!$Subject){?>style="display:none"<?php } ?>>
```

Comment: thanks, but i don't wish to hide the content if the condition is met, i just would like the div tag added if the condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to assume the whole context of your question (it would be good to write a little bit more about where the value for `$subject` comes from and what values it might be).

But assuming that `$subject` can be a specified set of values, you could try something like this:

```
$text = 'Some arbitrary text';

$allowedWrappers = array(
    'one'   => 'someID',
    'two'   => 'anotherID',
    'three' => 'yetAnotherID'
);

if(isset($subject) && in_array($subject, $allowedWrappers)) {
    echo '<div id="'.$allowedWrappers[$subject].'"><p>'.$text.'</p></div>';
} else {
    echo '<p>'.$text.'</p>';
}
```